# Is there any way to split the columns of list to rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In pandas, I want to change the data format as below.
In my thought, I have only idea with reading line by line with open('filename') and parse after readline.
Is there any way to to this in python pandas.

From

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| A | [1,2,3] |
| B | [4,5,6] |

to

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 3 |
| B | 4 |
| B | 5 |
| B | 6 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `explode`:

```
df = df.explode('Column B')
```

Another way via `list comprehension`:

```
d = {'Column A': {0: 'A', 1: 'B'}, 'Column B': {0: [1, 2, 3], 1: [4, 5, 6]}}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df = pd.DataFrame([[x] + [z] for x, y in df.values for z in y],columns=df.columns)
```

Comment: Thank you. It really helps my programming.